# Segmentation Fault after 2.3.3 upgrade

Tags: magento2

I was going to update from 2.3.2-p2 to 2.3.3-p1. I ran the composer update and everything worked. Now when I run any command it says segmentation fault. In working with my host this is what they have found-

I am seeing that that before it segfaults it is looping over the env.php and config.php over a thousand times.

Reviewing the stace, I am seeing that it is timing out on fd5 over and over between each call.

It looks like it is looping through resolving the store code and setting the locale.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else run across this here is the answer-

rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*